# Effect of Adding 'union' Keyword on Predefined Struct

Tags: c++, struct

I received some specs and a header file defining some structs to be used for a project. On of the structs that is used like a container had a use of `union` I don't think I've seen before. Shown below is similar setup to how the structs are defined:

```
typedef enum PayloadType
{
    PAYLOAD_A,
    PAYLOAD_B
};
struct A_Payload
{
    bool boolPayload;
};

struct B_Payload
{
    char messagePayload[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
};
struct standardPayload
{
    A_Payload aPayload;
    B_Payload bPayload;
};
struct containerPayload
{
    PayloadType type;
    union standardPayload stPayload;  // g++ doesn't like this
                                      // require -fpermissive to compile
};
```

Does the use of the `union` keyword in the last struct make the fields defined in `struct standardPayload` occupy the same space, as if it were defined like this? Which way is correct or acceptable, if any?

```
union struct standardPayload
{
    A_Payload aPayload;
    B_Payload bPayload;
};
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: @0x499602D2 thanks Effect vs Affect haha. Didn't study English in college.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the use of the `union` keyword in the last struct make the fields defined in `struct standardPayload` occupy the same space, as if it were defined like this?

No. It’s simply invalid here since `standardPayload` is not a `union`.

I am guessing that `standardPayload` used to be a `union` and was, at some time in the past, changed to a `struct`. Declaring a variable as `union X` is similar to declaring it `struct X` in C.

In C++, using either is obviously not required, and nor is `typedef enum` (at the top of your code) – a sign that this code is actually part of a C header rather than C++.

Comment: I think you're right that at one point standardPayload was a union. Especially with the enumeration field in the "containerPayload" to specify what type of "payload" it was. Some pertinent information could be that this struct was meant to be passed through POSIX message queues.